# Storing a graph with Core Plot without displaying it

Tags: core-plot

Is there a way to make Core Plot render a graph even if it is not displayed? I need to do some graphs to share them as images but I can't ask the user to display all plots first so I can save images of them once they are drawn to the screen.

If there is no such possibility: Do you know any other solutions that support simple XY charts with lines and dots.

Answer (score 1):

Core Plot graphs are Core Animation layers. Set the frame to the desired size when you create the graph, set it up normally, and call `-imageOfLayer` to render it to an `NSImage` on the Mac or `UIImage` on iOS. You can also call `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` to render it to PDF.